# Debugging link - Link Does not display Image

Tags: html

I am working on a site. The 1st link works perfectly but the other are not showing the image. I have tried to observe the code but could not debug it. Can anyone please help me out? Thanks.

```
  <a href="http://58288iexfdp1lwci0h-9r13c9s.hop.clickbank.net/?tid=COOKBOOK" target="_blank">
    <img src="cookbook.jpg" style="height: 236px; width: 320px;"/>
  </a>
  <a href="http://6b865fo5jgp9ou742emfsh9v8l.hop.clickbank.net/?tid=CB=MONEY" target="_blank">
    <img src="money.jpg" style="height: 236px; width: 320px;"/>
  <a href="http://09980bkznoq6nmbkxdfao80r34.hop.clickbank.net/?tid=ABS" target="_blank">
    <img src="abs.jpg" style="height: 236px; width: 320px;"/>
  <a href="http://f52e1kf3eoyxov2si8tj3lctde.hop.clickbank.net/?tid=DIET" target="_blank">
    <img src="diet.jpg" style="height: 236px; width: 320px;"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `<a>` aren't closed, i.e. you are missing `</a>` on the links that doesn't work.

```
<a href="http://58288iexfdp1lwci0h-9r13c9s.hop.clickbank.net/?tid=COOKBOOK" target="_blank">
  <img src="cookbook.jpg" style="height: 236px; width: 320px;"/>
</a>
<a href="http://6b865fo5jgp9ou742emfsh9v8l.hop.clickbank.net/?tid=CB=MONEY" target="_blank">
  <img src="money.jpg" style="height: 236px; width: 320px;"/>
</a>
<a href="http://09980bkznoq6nmbkxdfao80r34.hop.clickbank.net/?tid=ABS" target="_blank">
  <img src="abs.jpg" style="height: 236px; width: 320px;"/>
</a>
<a href="http://f52e1kf3eoyxov2si8tj3lctde.hop.clickbank.net/?tid=DIET" target="_blank">
  <img src="diet.jpg" style="height: 236px; width: 320px;"/> 
</a>
```

Comment: @StartupCrazy Its not in the code you posted, that only has one closing `a`

Comment: Sorry, I am a little tired. I saw your code and thought it was mine.

Answer (score 1):

You closed only the first `<a>` tag.

```
<a href="http://58288iexfdp1lwci0h-9r13c9s.hop.clickbank.net/?tid=COOKBOOK" target="_blank">
  <img src="cookbook.jpg" style="height: 236px; width: 320px;"/>
</a>
<a href="http://6b865fo5jgp9ou742emfsh9v8l.hop.clickbank.net/?tid=CB=MONEY" target="_blank">
    <img src="money.jpg" style="height: 236px; width: 320px;"/>
</a>
<a href="http://09980bkznoq6nmbkxdfao80r34.hop.clickbank.net/?tid=ABS" target="_blank">
    <img src="abs.jpg" style="height: 236px; width: 320px;"/>
</a>
<a href="http://f52e1kf3eoyxov2si8tj3lctde.hop.clickbank.net/?tid=DIET" target="_blank">
    <img src="diet.jpg" style="height: 236px; width: 320px;"/> 
</a>
```